# Java/Android Regex expression to allow names that may have apostrophe and/or hyphen

Tags: java, android, regex

My user name validation currently only allows upper and/or lower case letters , however I want to support:

Regular names like "James Bond" **OR**  Montagu-Stuart-Wortley-Mackenzie **OR** De'wayne **OR** De' wayne (notice the space after apostrophe) **OR** M'ontagu-S'tuart-W'ortley-M' ackenzie (space,apostrophe and hyphen allowed)

Here is current code:

```
 private void checkFirstNameInput(){
        String firstName = edtFirstName.getText().toString();
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^A-Za-z]");
        Matcher matcherFirstName = p.matcher(firstName);
        boolean firstNameValid = firstName.trim().length() >= 1 && !matcherFirstName.find();

        if(firstNameValid){
            edtFirstName.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.check_icon), null);
            edtFirstName.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.textfield_gray));
            APrefs.registeringUser.setFirstName(edtFirstName.getText().toString().trim());

        }else{
            edtFirstName.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, null, null);
            edtFirstName.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.textfield_gray));

        }
        txtError.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        checkNextButton();



    }
```

I tried ^[a-zA-Z'-]$ and also search other posts, but no success.

Thanks & much appreciated.

Comment: Try this pattern: `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\\p{L}' -]+");` and use `.matches()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
^[a-zA-Z'\\-\\s]+$
```

I've tested it now and it works (already escaped for Java, don't add more slashes)

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z'\\-\\s]+$");
Matcher matcherFirstName = pattern.matcher("M'ontagu-S'tuart-W'ortley-M' ackenzie");
matcherFirstName.find(); //true
```